# How can I update local repositories only if remotes are ahead

Tags: git, batch-file, cmd

Hello guys I am currently working under windows (puke) , but I want to write simple bat file that executes every 15 minutes checks if my local repos are behind master remote repository and pulls if true otherwise wait another 15 minutes (time is not important actually). So far I've done this , but it doesn't seem to work also I haven't figured out how I will keep the file executing.. schtask?

```
@echo off

CD /d D:\Repositories\Mobile\mobile
git checkout master
FIND "behind" | git status -uno
IF %errorlevel% EQU 0     
git pull

CD /d D:\Repositories\website\website
git checkout master
FIND "behind" | git status -uno
IF %errorlevel% EQU 0     
git pull

EXIT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion this is a bad idea.

`git pull` updates local branches with commits from one or more remotes. If this happens while you're in the middle of working on something your code could easily break and / or generate conflicts. `pull`ing should only be done deliberately.

`git fetch`, on the other hand, is safe to run. This will update your local tracking branches (e.g. `origin/master`), and you can manually merge changes into your local branches (e.g. `master`) at your convenience.

As it happens, this is related to the reason your script isn't working. Git only knows that a branch is behind its remote after a `fetch` (which `pull` does implicitly). If you never `fetch`, you'll never see a branch being `behind`. You may want to update your environment to run `git fetch` regularly, without the `behind` check.

If you really do want to merge `origin/master` into `master` automatically on a schedule it should be done after `git fetch`.

Comment: To be completely honest I actually use alias `git config --global alias.up '!git remote update -p; git merge --ff-only @{u}'` and I do git up instead of git pull... Anyway I am not sure how my script will know if my local repo is behind or not only with git fetch? I am newbie at this and I must have to re-think it I guess.

Comment: @kuskmen, Git is designed to be distributed. It works just fine on your laptop without any server at all. It never looks anywhere but its local repository unless you explicitly tell it to. That's essentially what `git fetch` does. I've never used `git remote update -p`, but it looks like this should also do a `fetch`. The key is that you won't see `behind` messages until you do a `fetch`. Git simply doesn't know that there are any new commits until then, so it has no idea that your local branch is behind. `git fetch`, then `pull` or `merge` or even your `up` alias, should work.

Comment: yea , I get it now , thanks a lot . Now I tried with fetch and now I got  `Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged, and have X and Y different commits each, respectively.` Which should be easy to fix , but it interupts my script and I can't continue.. :/

Comment: @kuskmen, that's one of the many complications of automatically merging (either explicitly or through `git pull`), and one of the reasons I suggested not automating that part of the process. I'm glad you got the `fetch` part working, though.

Comment: Okay , what do you suggest of solution to the problem that every time I want to develop something new I have to do fetch/pull master before creating new branch or something? Alias? I kinda don't like spaming git pull / git status  24/7  or this is the way its done?

Comment: @kuskmen, if I care about upstream updates (sometimes I might not) I would simply `git fetch` or `git pull`, then create a branch and start working. This reduces the number of fetches to something much less "spammy", increases the chances that each fetch will actually do something, and makes talking to the remote an explicit part of my workflow. In my opinion the fact that my local repository doesn't automatically update itself with my remote isn't a problem to solve; it's simply a workflow to internalize.